# How to access apllication data via JSP + Embebed TomCat 7

Tags: jsp, tomcat7

I have a java aplication and i want to be able to access to some internal data(to read and write) using JSP pages. (Configuration, Alarms, Logs, ...)

I'm using embebed tomcat, it runs inside one thread of my application:

```
public class webServer implements Runnable {
    public void run(){
        try {   
            Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
            tomcat.setPort(9080);

            File docBase = new File("");
            tomcat.addWebapp(null,"",docBase.getAbsolutePath());
            tomcat.start();
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            //LifecycleException InterruptedException
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How JSP can access to some internal data? For example, if i have one variable named Alarms, that represents the alarm state of my application ( the value of this variable can change), How can i use an JSP page to read its value? Can this be performed with JSP?